# Any way to dynamically declare a dictionary in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I *believe* a dictionary is correct for this job, but am not sure. The application: Parsing CNC machine code (text), identifying sequences in the code and storing a dictionary specific to each sequence. Number of sequences varies. Line numbers will be stored when important code is found. When that is complete the text can be iterated over one more time, using the stored line numbers as flags to make changes as needed.

I have solved this problem in the past but the solution involved looping like crazy and reading the same data repeatedly. It should be much cleaner.

Here is where I've gotten with the logic for this new attempt. I would like to dynamically declare a dictionary, but don't know if it is possible.

```
Dim in_list As New List(Of String)
Dim sequences As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, Decimal))
Try
    Dim S100 As New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
    Dim S200 As New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
    '
    'Dim S5000 as New Dict... come on, now.
    '
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)
    Dim sequence_number As Integer = 0
    Dim line_number As Integer = -1
    Do While reader.Peek <> -1
        Dim L As String = reader.ReadLine
        line_number += 1
        in_list.Add(L)
        'Will be parsing differently, but string.indexof() for example:
        If L.IndexOf("M6") > -1 Then  'M6 marks the beginning of a sequence.
            sequence_number += 100
            If sequence_number = 100 Then
                sequences.Add(sequence_number, S100)
                sequences(sequence_number).Add("M6", line_number)
            End If
            If sequence_number = 200 Then
                sequences.Add(sequence_number, S200)
                sequences(sequence_number).Add("M6", line_number)
            End If
            '
            ' If sequence_number = 5000...
            ' really dude?
            '
        End If

        'Below is not the problem, but may help for suggestions in case
        '    a dictionary should not be used, or any suggestion.
        If sequence_number > 0 And sequences.ContainsKey(sequence_number) Then
            If L.IndexOf("F") > -1 Then
                If Not sequences(sequence_number).ContainsKey("first_F") Then
                    sequences(sequence_number).Add("first_F", line_number)
                End If
                If Not sequences(sequence_number).ContainsKey("last_F") Then
                    sequences(sequence_number).Add("last_F", line_number)
                Else
                    sequences(sequence_number).Item("last_F") = line_number
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

A bit of the code I am parsing is:

```
N100(5/16" CENTER CUTTING MILL)
M6T4  
G0G80G90G54X.44Y0.S1550M3
G43H4Z1./M8
G98G81Z-.005R.4F3. 
X.37Y0.
X.3Y0. 
G80M9
G91G28Z0.M19 
G90
M01
```

I won't actually be using a simple string.IndexOf() as shown in this code. I will be using functions to find certain codes (e.g. "F" or "G"), make sure they not in a (comment), sometimes extract the numeric value of the code, etc.

Comment: This seems like an ideal job for a regular expression. Could you show examples in hex of the data and patterns you are looking for? I guess I don't quite understand what the whole thing achieves, but I am pretty sure I can show you a better way to deal with this.

Comment: Examples of the data would be nice.  That code doesnt use the S dictionaries nor do we know what the data represents.  A dictionary is great when there can be only one entry for the key.  Finding stuff no longer needs to involve "looping like crazy " with a little linq.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. I don't know what you mean by "in hex of the data". I'll post an example.

Comment: Your `sequences` - a dictionary of dictionaries - appears to be the general approach you want.  And you can create the internal dictionaries dynamically, if that's what you are asking.  Something like; `If Not sequences.ContainsKey(X) Then sequences.Add(X, new Dictionary(String, Decimal))`

Comment: Ok so the actual beginning of a sequence is N, and then the sequence number, and description. And since this is G-Code, M6T4 is a tool change to tool slot 4. What exactly do you want as an end result, in your own words? What are you going to use it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you need to *declare* the `Dictionary` ahead of time, do you?

In this section:

```
sequence_number += 100
If sequence_number = 100 Then
    sequences.Add(sequence_number, S100)
    sequences(sequence_number).Add("M6", line_number)
End If
'
' If sequence_number = 5000...
' really dude?
'
```

You can use the properties of the `sequences` Dictionary to avoid all the repeated `If` statements, something like:

```
sequence_number += 100

If Not sequences.ContainsKey(sequence_number) Then
   'you have not defined the dictionary for this sequence
   'first do that
    sequences.Add(sequence_number, new Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)) 
End If

'at this point you have a Dictionary for this sequence_number, so use it
sequences(sequence_number).Add("M6", line_number)
```

Comment: Dictionaries seem very clumsy to me, and not the ideal tool for a hierarchical data representation. It has a distinct VB6 smell.